# Warning: filter_has_var() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given

Tags: php, filter

```
<?php 
    // Check for posted data
    if(filter_has_var('INPUT_POST', 'data')){
        echo 'Data Found';
    } else {
        echo 'No Data';
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <input type="text" name="data">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I get this error and the input is not changing to "Data Found" when I submit a data.

> Warning: filter_has_var() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_front_to_back/filters.php on line 3
> No Data

Comment: You want `INPUT_POST`, without quotes. That's a constant. See [the manual](https://www.php.net/filter_has_var) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'data')){
   echo 'Data found';
}else{
   echo 'No Data';
```

Enclosing with `'` means that is a string, you must pass `PHP constant` in the first parameter.

First parameter supports : `INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, INPUT_ENV`

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the answer without having to change the syntax.

Comment: Enclosing with ' means that is a string, you must pass PHP constant in the first parameter